# Allow unfiltered HTML for not logged in users when saving a post

Tags: users, wp-insert-post, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using this code:

```
$var1 = $_GET["t1s2ninput"];
$var2 = $_GET["t1s2pinput"];
$new_post = array (
    'post_title'    => 'Title <dl class="variation"> <dt>Variation: </dt> <dd>'. $var1 .'</dd> </dl>',
    'post_author'   => 5,
    'post_content'  => 'Lorem ipsum',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'product',
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, 72, "product_cat");

$var3 = $var2 / 1;
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $var3 );

global $woocommerce; 
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($post_id, 1);
```

When I'm logged as admin it works flawlessly, however in any other case (logged out, other user...) the title of the post doesn't work as it should, the `HTML` tags (in this case `<dl class="variation">` and the others) disappear.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

### Capabilties - for guests?

Your problem is that a guest doesn't have *any* capabilities. And when posts get processed, they need to pass certain checks. One is [`unfiltered_html`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#unfiltered_html). From Codex:

> Allows user to post HTML markup or even JavaScript code in pages, posts, comments and widgets.
>
> **Note**: Enabling this option for untrusted users may result in their posting malicious or poorly formatted code.
>
> **Note**: In WordPress Multisite, only Super Admins have the `unfiltered_html` capability.

To still get it into the DB, you should encode it. The following example first does trimming of leading and trailing white space. Then converts all characters to their encoded equivalent, encodes single and double quotes and returns it in proper UTF-8 (this is recommended as pre PHP 5.4 versions used the ISO-8859-1 charset). If you're using PHP 5.4+ you could as well add  `| ENT_HTML5` to the flags/2nd arg to convert it to HTML5. Now there's the **important** part: Stripping off all unwanted tags using the WP global for allowed tags and PHPs [`strip_tags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). And finally we decode all HTML tags. Now your content should be able to be saved including the HTML.

```
$content = trim( $new_post['post_title'] );
$content = htmlentities( $content, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8" );
$content = strip_tags( $content, "<".join( "><", array_keys( $GLOBAL['allowedtags'] ) ).">" );
$content = html_entity_decode( $content );
```

The code isn't tested and I'm not completely sure if the `join` part works like that. `strip_tags()` expects a string and IIRC the `global $allowedtags` is an array and has the tag names without leading/trailing brackets as keys and the attributes as values. In case, you'll have to play around with it a bit (and please file an [edit] in case I somewhere was wrong).

### Safe content

Aside from that, you're inserting unsafe and unchecked content directly retrieved via `$_GET`.  You should use the `esc_*()` functions or - even better - the native PHP [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) or [it's cousins](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php).

Comment: Thank you so much! That explanition is really well wrote, now I can understand it. Oh, about $_GET, I have already switched to $_POST, which is more secure.  Now I'm unsure about where should I use this code, I put it on the functions.php but the syntax wasn't right. Could you help me a little more? Thank you again!

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto `$_GET` isn't less/more secure than `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` - they just serve a different purpose. In other words, you still (and really!) need to check the values you receive via it. In my example, the `$content` is the HTML that you got inside the `post_title` value.

Comment: I understand. Well, in my case I don't think it would be insecure because that's not a form where the guest should fill, it's just some variables I have defined before in other page.
However I still don't get how to use your code, sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto No problem, but still: Don't input not validated and unsanitized data from the global context. You'll never know where they get intercepted. To your problem: The `$new_post['post_title']` is what needs to have HTML, right? And I'll change the answer to reflect that to give you more orientation. Simply said: Do what I showed you before you use `wp_insert_post()`.

Comment: Thank you again. Something is wrong, take a look: [image](http://i.imgur.com/kU15CdX.jpg). Maybe it's a semicolon instead of a comma in `$content = trim( $new_post['post_title'] )` and maybe there's an extra parenthesis `$content = strip_tags( $content, "<".join( "><", array_keys( $GLOBAL['allowedtags'] ) ).">" ) )`. I tried to fix it, but it gave me an error in the page.

Comment: "An error" is quite unspecific. Please read the error message -  the reason you get it is that it provides help finding the error ;). I fixed the typos, but we have to stop here. Keep in mind that answers on this site are meant to be guidance, not copy/paste-ready solutions. Anything from here should be done on your side with research on php.net and [so].

Comment: Thank you again. I know I should provide more details about the error but I'm really new to php and don't really understand the error message. I'll study more and find a way to make it work. Thank you.